# Can a 7 speed Derailleur work on a 8 speed cassette

Tags: derailleur, cassette, 7-speed

Can a 7 speed Derailleur work on a 8 speed cassette I have a extra 8 speed shifters? and a wheel that has a 8 speed cassette.

Comment: You might work?  Give it at try.

Comment: Are the rear derailleur and shifters indexed?

Answer (score 9):

8 speed shifter and cassette, 7 speed derailleur? You'll be fine. There's no "probably" about it.

6-, 7- and 8-speed gear is all cross-compatible in terms of chain width.

The only time you'd hit a problem is if the shifter and the cassette weren't made for the same number of gears, for example you could imagine a scenario (e.g. 7-speed cassette, 8-speed shifter) where you might click past the edge of the cassette. That would negatively impact your day.

Comment: Well, the shifter and derailleur need to have the same cable pull.

Comment: @Batman The cable pull per cog is the same. The derailleur stops need to be set, same as anytime you install one.

Comment: You can't stick a Shimano shifter with a sram derailleur and expect it to work cause the cable pull ratios of the shifter and derailleur are different.

Comment: Most of the incompatible cable pull problems started in the 9 speed era. Older SRAM derailluers have a 2:1 ratio the same as Shimano. This table covers all the details. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Gear-changing_Dimensions#REAR_SHIFTING_TABLES

Comment: That's a good link @FredtheMagicWonderDog.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. Depends somewhat on whether the shifter is compatible with the derailleur (Shimano 8-speed shifters generally will work okay with 7-speed derailleurs, but you can't usually do a Gripshift with a Shimano derailleur, to name a couple of examples.)

You'll have to adjust the limit screws and barrel adjuster, but you would have to do that any time you install a different derailleur.

Comment: I have shifters like this http://www.amazon.com/dp/B006Z0PM7A/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=3JR59IN00QRM6&coliid=IEU6N8H9QLL7K

Comment: You should be fine with any rear Derailuer that has a 2:1 ratio. If it is a Shimano 7spd, then no problem. Older SRAM can work as well.

Answer (score 1):

yes it will work. I tested it already. 6/7/8 speed chains are all the same width. so meaning. the cassette's width is the same too.